# pam_filter usage prevent passwd from working

Tags: linux, ldap, pam, passwd

I have PAM+LDAP SSL running on Debian Lenny, it works well. I always want to restrict who's able to connect, in the past I used pam_groupdn for that but I recently got a situation where I has to accept 2 different groups. So I used pam_filter like this :

pam_filter |(groupattribute=server)(groupattribute=restricted_server)

The problem is that with this statement, passwd doesn't work anymore with LDAP accounts.

Any idea why ?

Please find hereby some links to my config files :
Since serverfault.com only allow me to post 1 link, please find hereunder the link to other conf files :
http://pastebin.org/447148

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used pam_filter, but the usual LDAP query would in my opinion be

```
pam_filter (|(groupattribute=server)(groupattribute=restricted_server))
```

instead of

```
pam_filter |(groupattribute=server)(groupattribute=restricted_server)
```

you posted. Notice the extra parenthesis.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, thanks for the help.

Comment: No idea, anyobody ?